# Which source DC comics does this page (featuring the Batcave Frank Springer 1968 white/red-shaded version Repost for Batcave Batman #203) come from?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, episode-identification

**What is the source of the image below?**

[image]
<sub><sup>("*SECRETS OF THE BATCAVE - 1969*")</sup></sub>

---

Other similar versions of this picture have been published over the years:

Batcave Frank Springer
[Batman #203](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_1_203) (1968)
[image]

[Superman / Batman 24 (Ehapa)](http://www.dcpedia.de/wiki/index.php/Superman_/_Batman_24_(Ehapa)_-_1968) (1968)
[image]

[*Limited Collectors' Edition #37*](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Limited_Collectors%27_Edition_Vol_1_C-37) (1975)
[image]

Batcave 1968 from [Batman: In the Sixties](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_in_the_Sixties_(Collected)) (1999)
[image]

[Batman: Secrets of the Batcave](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman:_Secrets_of_the_Batcave) (2007)
[image]

Encyclopedia of Comic Book Heroes, Volume 1: Batman  (1976)
[image]

[Tales of the Dark Knight: Batman's First Fifty Years 1939-1989](https://matthewjagerextraextra.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/23010832.pdf) (1989)
[image]

Batcave Frank Springer inked Sketch
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A similar discussion with more images. No answer for your questions but might be useful if someone has similar question: https://community.cbr.com/showthread.php?158235-Batcave-Frank-Springer&p=5977857

Answer (score 10):

The appearance in [*Giant Batman* #203](https://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Batman-1940/Issue-203?id=17817) is the original.  A black-and-white version appeared on the cover of that issue.

[image: Giant Batman #203]

In the late 1960s, the 80-page *Giant Batman* was primarily a reprint series that appeared twice a year.  Generally, there was a theme to each issue (such as stories about major villains, or about the women in the Caped Crusader's life).  As you can see, for #203, the issue theme was "The Secrets of the Batcave."  Each issue's table of contents stated where the material in the issue had originally appeared, and occasionally indicated that the content was new to that issue.*

The contents page in #203 lists

> A BATMAN SPECIAL
> THE BATCAVE 1968

which indicates that the plan of the cave was new content.

[image: Batcave 1968]

The original black-and-white artwork for the two-page spread in #203 was evidently retained by DC and reused several times with different color schemes, including full-color versions and the 1969 red-and-white duotone.  For example, a poster of one recolored version was given away in 1977 as a prize for high-achieving students in the [SRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_Research_Associates) independent reading program used in may American elementary schools (including mine).

[image: SRA Poster]

A further question is who produced the artwork.  The Giant issue #203 actually falls right at a changeover in the art for the *Batman* series. The previous issue, #202, had been credited to Bob Kane, one of the co-creators of Batman and Robin.  However, Kane had apparently be getting the issues drawn and ghostwritten by others for years.  With issue #204, however, a new creative team was credited, including pencil artist [Irv Novick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irv_Novick) and inker [Joe Giella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Giella).  The Batmobile in the "Secrets of the Batcave—1968" is practically identical to the way Novick drew the the Batmobile starting in #204.  (The small rear view of the Batmobile, the drawing of the Batboat, and the models shown on the table on the cover also conform to the designs used during the period when Novick and Giella were working on the magazine.)  In contrast, the Batmobile from "Secrets of the Batcave—1968" is clearly dissimilar to the way the vehicle was shown in the immediately preceding "Bob Kane" issues.  The placement of the mask symbol at the front of the vehicle is particularly distinctive of the change in artistic styles.  Based on these facts (and some other artistic similarities), I think it is reasonable to conclude that the original artwork for the Batcave cutaway was produced by by Irv Novick, probably with Joe Giella inking.

There is an signature below the Batmobile, which I think is too messy to be legible (and may not even be complete).

[image: Illegible Signature]

However, the last letter, at least, does strongly resemble the way Irv Novick signed the "k" at the end of his name.  Here is another, clear, version of his signature for comparison.

[image: Novick's Signature]

Incidentally, the new depiction of the the 1968 Batcave was an expansion and update to an earlier plan shown in the first story reprinted in *Giant Batman* #203, "The 1,000 Secrets of the Batcave!" from 1948.

[image: Batcave 1948]

[The original 1948 issue](https://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Batman-1940/Issue-48?id=17624), #48, in which that story appeared also had a black-and-white version of the plan on the cover, which the cover of #203 was clearly an homage to.

*Actually, the very next *Giant Batman* issue, #208, was accidentally printed without a table of contents that listed where the various stories were being excerpted from.  However, that was corrected by printing the information in the letter column of the yet next issue, #213.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked, which is where that specific image comes from.

Comment: @bpvxxvqd I'm confused.  Are you asking specifically about where the 1969 red-and-white duotone (the first one shown in the question) appeared?

Comment: @Buzz Please, I want both

Comment: @bpvxxvqd I'm not sure what you mean by "both."  Do you mean the one from issue 203 and the 1969 red-and-white one?

Comment: @bpvxxvqd Well, I've identified which was the original version of the artwork.  I will see if I can figure out where the 1969 duotone came from, and I will add that to my answer if I manage to locate it.

Comment: It seems that
red shaded by photo editor
but We are still looking for the page source from DC comics versions

Comment: @bpvxxvqd If I located the source of the duotone, I will post here again.

Comment: I believe that the messy signature below the batmobile belongs to my uncle, Frank Springer. It just says Springer. I have attached [an image of one his signatures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4cAMm.jpg) for reference.