# What is the source of this painting of the Batcave's layout?

Tags: dc, batman, image-identification

What is the source of this painting of the Batcave's layout?
[image]

[Batman: Secrets of the Batcave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQFg6.jpg)
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Batman: Secrets of the Batcave [![enter image description here][2]][2]

https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman:_Secrets_of_the_Batcave [2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be from Batman #203, from August 1968:

[image]

> 1. If you’re reading this, you’re probably familiar with the feature, but to recap, Secrets of the Batcave — 1968 is four pages, including a two-page splash of Wayne Manor and the Batcave, a page the explains the intracacies of Batman and Robin’s utility belts and a page on various other equipment, including the Batarang and Batplane. Batman #203 was an issue filled with reprints spotlighting various aspects of Batman’s arsenal.
>
> <sub>(source: [13 QUICK THOUGHTS on the Glorious SECRETS OF THE BATCAVE — 1968](https://13thdimension.com/13-quick-thoughts-on-the-glorious-secrets-of-the-batcave-1968/), from 13th Dimension)</sub>

More info, including the full map, is available at the 13th Dimension link above.

(Process: I did a reverse image search of the blueprint image from the question, found a few references that narrowed it down to "a 1968 Batman comic", and then searched for "batcave 1968 diagram", which led to relevant results.)

Comment: Sorry
But this was the poster design in Batman #203  https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT8TX.jpg  not this https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQFg6.jpg

Comment: @bqvwvpd - Then why have you accepted this answer?

Comment: I won't cause disturbance
Did he cancel accepting the answer?

Comment: @bqvwvpd There's a comprehensive list of variants on this similar question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/239781/21154 The one you found is listed as being from "Batman: Secrets of the Batcave" (2007), although I don't have it and can't confirm.

Comment: @bqvwvpd What do you mean, "Did he cancel accepting the answer?" Nobody else can unaccept answers to your questions - only you can do that.

Comment: @fez   I came up with an answer do I add it? Batman: Secrets of the Batcave (2007)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhw60.jpg  https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman:_Secrets_of_the_Batcave